# Give Undead mobs instant health

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there any way to give an undead mob instant health?

I've tried `/effect @e[team=Undead] instant_health` but it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by instant healthy, restore them to full health? Also, do you want to affect all undead mobs?

Comment: instant healthy can let undead mob such as zombie dead

Comment: so you want to heal the mobs

Answer (score 3):

Undead mobs (zombie, zombie pigman) have backward health effects.
Instant Health damages them,
Instant Damage heals them.
Try using instant damage.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give specific mobs (in your case Skeletons and Zombies) an effect you can do it like so  `/effect @e{type=<mob>} <effect> 1 1`

Eg. `/effect @e{type=Skeleton} instant_damage 1 1`
- This will will heal the skeleton. Same goes with the zombie.

If you want to target mobs in a specific area,just add r=desiredrange.

Eg. `/effect @e{type=Skeleton,r=60} instant_damage 1 1`
This will heal the Skeleton within the 60 block range of the command block.